# Confusion in callback function in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, mern

[image][image]I am confused in callback function execution in javascript. I am not sure that what is the execution flow of it. Our asynchronous code is executed after our main function in javasript in call stack.

I have used asynchronous function (setTimeout() ) inside the synchronous function(add), when I return the value directly from asynchronous function (without using callback i.e. return a + b) it is returning nothing. while when I am calling the callback function from asynchronous function (callback(a+b) ) then it will return the actual sum which is correct one.

So, I am confused that if our asynchrounous function is running after our main function in call stack then how our callback function is getting executed after that.

Comment: This is expected behavior in javascript, to get a better understanding you should understand how javascript EVENT LOOP works.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xof_TiENzXE

Comment: Please include your code directly in your question instead of sharing images of code.

Comment: Do NOT put code into images.  This makes it hard to read on mobile, makes it hard for people with vision disabilities, code can't be search indexed, makes it impossible for people providing answers to copy/paste code into answers, etc...  Do not put code into images.  Paste the code as text and format it properly as code in the editor.  You can fix your question now by using the "edit" link below your question.

Comment: Your `return a+b` is returning from the setTimeout callback not from your `add()` function.  That `setTimeout` callback is called in the future, long after the `add()` function has already returned.  This is because `setTimeout()` is asynchronous and non-blocking.  Plus, in your first version of `add()`, nothing ever calls the callback.

Comment: @RahulSharma - It's not so much how the event loop works, but how non-blocking, asynchronous functions work in Javascript.  Yes, they use the event loop, but you don't need to know much about the event loop, rather you need to understand what a non-blocking asynchronous function is, how it works and when it will call its callback.

Comment: Note that return cannot jump multiple functions. For example if you have `function a () { function b () { function c () { return 'hello' } }; b()}` if you call `a()` it will return nothing because that return statement belongs to `c()` and `c` was never called. Similarly in your code the `return` statement belongs to the function `() => {...` not the `setTimeout` or `add`

Comment: as per your reply... if "return a+b" is not  running because of asynchronous call is executing after the call stack is empty.. then how callback is executing in second example which is also in setTimeout function...I think I am missing something